# php How could I get keynames of an associative array

Tags: php, key, associative-array

I have this array:

```
$rooms["100"]['guestcount'] = 2;
$rooms["200"]['guestcount'] = 2;
$rooms["300"]['guestcount'] = 1;
```

Associative Key represents the roomnumber, the capacity "guestcount" of this room.

How could I read the indexkey (100-300)?
So I want to have all associative keys to print this out.

I tried it with:

```
$roomnumbers = array_unique(array_keys($rooms));
```

But I get an Error vor "Array to string conversion":

Could you help me please?
I want to use the roomnumber step by step for another doing.

Comment: `echo $roomnumbers;` obviously? `print_r($roomnumbers)` instead

Comment: With echo $roomnumbers I get this error above.
And print_r gives me an overview of the array, the keys and values.

Comment: This is not reproducible. Please refer https://3v4l.org/G2856 .
How did you give the result? Try echo implode(',',$roomnumbers);

Comment: And what's the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you initialize the array $room? This code should work.

```
$rooms = [];
$rooms["100"]['guestcount'] = 2;
$rooms["200"]['guestcount'] = 2;
$rooms["300"]['guestcount'] = 1;

$roomnumbers = array_unique(array_keys($rooms));
var_dump($roomnumbers);
```

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(100)
  [1]=>
  int(200)
  [2]=>
  int(300)
}
```

you can process the array with keys as following.

```
$table = '<table>';
foreach ($rooms as $roomNumber => $room) {
    $table .= '<tr><td>' . $roomNumber . '</td><td>' . $room['guestcount'] . '</td></tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
print $table;
```

Comment: Could I get from this a new array only with the roomnumbers?
Because, when I want to print the roomnumbers and the guestcount in an html-table, I need go through one by one to the end of the array.
Var_dump only shows me the hole array.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how you can process this array and get the keys and values to an example dummy table

Comment: But without a foreach loop it doesn't possible or?
Or is there like in the db-world with msqli_fetch_array something only for arrays?